# Браузер не отображает изображение

Tags: html, css, spring

Я написал вроде бы правильно код, но почему браузер не видит мое изображение которое я хочу поставить на фон.
Когда хочу отобразить картинка выглядит вот так будто файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>




        <title>Home Page</title>

    </head>

         <body>
             <img class='img' src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/home.jpg'>
         <style>
         html { 
             background-image: url(/images/home.jpg);
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-size: cover;
             position: relative;
             height: 100%;
         }
         </style>

         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">School</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Наш университет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Электронный журнал</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Студенты</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Карьера</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <div class="container">

    </div>


    <div class="bg">
        <div class ="pokaz">
            <form action="allStudents" method="post">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в том месте, где вы задаёте адрес background-image используйте `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` для формирования пути к `/images/home.jpg`

Comment: <img class='img' src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/home.jpg'> вот так?

Comment: background-image: url("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/home.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать jstl атрибут url:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
  <body>
    <img class='img' src='<c:url value="/images/home.jpg"/>'>
```

Comment: не помогло((((9